# Efficient way to find missing rows across multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Given the following schema, where members can share ownership of posts:

```
member: id, name, ...
post_owner: member_id, post_id
post: id, created, ...
```

What's the most efficient query to find users who haven't made a post in the last 90 days.

I thought of this, but it seems inefficient:

```
select *
from member
where member_id not in (
    select member_id
    from post p
    join post_owner po on po.post_id = p.id
    where created > subdate(now(), 90))
```

Assume there is an index on `post(created)` and all foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, m.name 
FROM member m 
LEFT JOIN post_owner po ON m.id = po.member_id 
LEFT JOIN post p ON po.post_id = p.id AND p.created >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Hint: compare `p.created` to a constant so as to make use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
SELECT m.id, m.name 
From post p
INNER JOIN post_owner po ON po.post_id = p.id AND
RIGHT JOIN member m ON m.id = po.member_id
where  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) <= created
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name 
FROM member m 
LEFT JOIN post_owner po ON m.id = po.member_id 
LEFT JOIN post p ON po.post_id = p.id AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), p.created) <= 90
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Comment: You're very close but it can be much more efficient with the date comparison and the table order.  Try harder :)